# Top 50 records by DATALENGTH of a field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-limit

Azure SQL Server 2016 - I'm having trouble with the syntax to combine `TOP`, `MAX` and `DATALENGTH` to get a list of the Top 50 records from a table by `DATALENGTH` of a specific field.

The field I need to do the `DATALENGTH` on is called `Text`.  I **don't** actually want the `Text` field returned in the results - What I want returned are fields called `CaptureId` and `TaskSourceId` from the 50 records with the largest `DATALENGTH` in the `Text` field, as well as the `DATALENGTH` amount.

I tried this, but it did not work, with an error about CaptureId not being contained in an aggregate function or GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT TOP 50 
    CaptureId, 
    TaskSourceId, 
    MAX(DATALENGTH([Text]))
FROM 
    Data.Capture
```

Can someone please help me correct this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `max`. Just sort the records:

```
select top 50 
  captureid, tasksourceid, datalength(text) as text_len
from data.capture
order by datalength(text) desc
```

This will not care about ties and return up to 50 rows.

If you want to account ties regarding text field data length, use `top 50 with ties` instead of simple `top 50`. It may return more than 50 records in this case.

Comment: Hi Kamil, it seems you posted your answer while I was editing.  I edited to mention that I also need to have the actual `DATALENGTH` of the `Text` field returned as well.

Comment: Ah, I see you just edited your answer.  Thanks!  I will try this now and mark as the answer asap.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thanks Kamil.